# Use Flash E4X with Bing

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing, e4x, bing

I'm using Action Script 3.0, and am using E4X to parse some XML files.  It was working fine, until I began using Bing's xml result file.

Here's a sample of Bing's XML result:

```
<web:Web xmlns:web="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web">
    <web:Total>85700000</web:Total>
    <web:Offset>0</web:Offset>
    <web:Results>
      <web:WebResult>
        <web:Title>HELLO! - The place for celebrity news - hellomagazine.com</web:Title>
```

I need to get info from the WebResult node, but the colon in the web:WebResult is throwing me off.

I've tried the following:

```
var title:String = xml..Results.WebResult[0].text();
```

to get the first title from the Web Results, but it doesn't work.  I think that it can't find the WebResult node because this returns 0

```
var results:int = xml..Results.WebResult.length();
```

Any suggestions on how to get information from this kind of XML file using E4X?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: 
First, define the namespace variable 'web' by writing this

```
var xhtml:Namespace = new Namespace("schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web";);
```

Then, add 'web::' before each element in the E4X expression. For example,

```
xml..Results.WebResult.length();
```

becomes

```
xml..web::Results.web::WebResult.length();
```